# Propagate local time over NTP to LAN

Tags: cisco, switch, local-area-network, ntp

I have synchronized my L3 switch to an external time server, this is working correctly. However I'm in Europe and we have CET/CEST switching and I get UTC from the configured time server. I did setup the timezone and the summer-time in my switch (shows the correct time when I use "show clock"), but my switch propagates the NTP (UTC) time towards my LAN. (I know this is the normal operation)

My question is, can I propagate with NTP the local (CET/CEST) time towards my LAN clients, or are there any other method to do this? The problem I have that I can't setup CET/CEST switching on my clients, they do not support this. (I have PLCs in my LANs, and they're only capable of GMT settings)

Are there any solution for this, or I must use a separate time source?

Thank you very much!

Comment: First of all, GMT != UTC! But I think this wasn't your question.

Answer (score 3):

> can I propagate with NTP the local (CET/CEST) time towards my LAN
> clients, or are there any other method to do this?

No, not with NTP. NTP has no concept of local time at all, its all UTC. [All the packet contains](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/info/ntp-packet.htm) is a few time stamps with seconds and fractions of a second from an epoch.

Do not attempt to configure "wrong" offset NTP servers to do local time zone offsets. I have never seen this work, it makes good robust NTP configurations difficult.

General purpose computers have (and keep updated) a tz database such that they can be configured with say `Europe/Berlin` and have correct local time even when the rules change.

A rugged, embedded, or otherwise dumb computer may not have a tzdata package, or a means to update it, or reasonable time and date software. Almost certainly your PLC is lacking some of these. That [KB article on how to sync time to controllers](https://www.myomron.com/index.php?action=kb&article=1556) is missing details on what format or time zone everything is in, which doesn't raise my confidence that internally is a reasonable UTC clock with time zone offsets.

Unfortunately your options may be limited to exporting data to a system with a full featured clock, leaving it on UTC forever, or cursing daylight savings time every year when fixing offsets.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful! I must have to do that somehow, so I think I will create my own local time with one of the PLCs then and propagate it through Ethernet/IP.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can propagate whatever time zone's time through NTP, you just need to make sure

- there will be only 1 time source on your LAN to mitigate the danger that your clients will receive conflicting timestamp messages and switch back and forth
- your time source will broadcast the time in the time zone you intend to

In other words: If the time source in your LAN is the L3 switch, this would be the device which either has a setting to "traslate" the time zone for NTP clients or not. In case your L3 switch isn't capable of that, you will need a different time source which is.

Comment: Do you know a method for this using Cisco IE-2000 or you suspect that I should use a separate device?

Comment: IIUC, the IE-2000 is running Cisco IOS (not to bei confused with iOS). I cannot find anything in IOS docs which seems to help and you cannot run any own code on IOS. So sounds to me like you will need a separate device.

Comment: IIUC, the IE-2000 is running Cisco IOS (not to bei confused with iOS). I cannot find anything in IOS docs which seems to help and you cannot run any own code on IOS. So sounds to me like you will need a separate device.

Comment: Are you sure your PLCs' NTP client implementation is that incomplete it cannot handle time zones properly? What make or model would that be?

Comment: Omron NJ/NS series, as you can see in the link below you can only modify the time zone, but can't change anything related to DST.
https://www.myomron.com/index.php?action=kb&article=1556

Comment: Two links: https://automation.omron.com/en/mx/support/resources/sample-code/nx-nj-daylight-savings-time-adjustment-sample-code-project and https://forums.mrplc.com/index.php?/topic/26468-etn21-time-sync-and-dst/ No idea what an FB would be, though.

Comment: Are you sure the PLC does not know to handle DST or is that just your assumption?

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't know how to handle it, I will do that compensation with a function and pass that compensated time through Ethernet/IP to my other devices.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, don't try to get NTP to do anything but UTC, it's a bad idea. DST is usually handled in a couple different ways within SCADA systems, some run winter time all year round, some run UTC all year round, and some use a different sync mechanism for field devices where you sync time throgh the control protocol (IEC-104 for example). I'd recommend talking to the support over at Omron, they might give you the fastest answer on how to handle this.